# ffmpeg is complaining about ACT flag violation in some of our DNxHD videos. Could this be safely ignored? Why?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-codecs, data-integrity

We've been using ffmpeg/ffprobe for checking video file integrity. If ffmpeg returns anything in its stderr, we'd know something's not right.

For some videos, an error like this will show up in the stderr.

> [dnxhd @ 00000212f6fc3e80] ACT flag set, in violation of frame header.

But I have no idea what an ACT flag actually is.

Digging through the ffmpeg code returns this block (dnxhddec.c):

```c
static int dnxhd_decode_macroblock(const DNXHDContext *ctx, RowContext *row,
                                   AVFrame *frame, int x, int y)
{
    ...
    if (ctx->mbaff) {
        interlaced_mb = get_bits1(&row->gb);
        qscale = get_bits(&row->gb, 10);
    } else {
        qscale = get_bits(&row->gb, 11);
    }
    act = get_bits1(&row->gb);
    if (act) {
        if (!ctx->act) {
            static int act_warned;
            if (!act_warned) {
                act_warned = 1;
                av_log(ctx->avctx, AV_LOG_ERROR,
                       "ACT flag set, in violation of frame header.\n");
            }
        } else if (row->format == -1) {
            row->format = act;
        } else if (row->format != act) {
            row->format = 2; // Variable
        }
    }
    ...
```

And in the same file, another code snippet shows:

```c
static int dnxhd_decode_header(DNXHDContext *ctx, AVFrame *frame,
                               const uint8_t *buf, int buf_size,
                               int first_field)
{
    ...
    ctx->act = buf[0x2C] & 1;
    if (ctx->act && ctx->cid_table->cid != 1256 && ctx->cid_table->cid != 1270)
        av_log(ctx->avctx, AV_LOG_WARNING,
               "Adaptive color transform in an unsupported profile.\n");
    ...
```

So I'm guessing ACT = Adaptive Color Transform

And here's the message from the commit which changed the line:

> Christophe Gisquet  Christophe Gisquet, 5 years ago   (October 4th,
> 2015 4:06pm)
>
> dnxhddec: better support for 4:4:4
>
> Profiles 1256 & 1270 (currently) signal at the frame header and MB
> levels the colorspace used, either RGB or YUV. While a MB-level
> varying colorspace is not supported, whether it is constant can be
> tracked so as to determine the exact colorspace.
>
> This requires having bitdepth and the ACT and 4:4:4 flags, in turn
> needing the CID. Because setting those before having validated enough
> things may result in invalid/unset DSP fucntions, setting the bitdepth
> in the context is delayed.
>
> It is not tested against a true RGB sequence, though.

By reading the commit, this looks like it should only affect 4:4:4 videos, but actually all of our videos with this error are 4:2:2 at the moment. (Codec ID <strike>1237</strike>1242 1080i)

The <strike>only</strike>first useful result about Profiles (Codec ID) I could find so far is this:
http://docs.red.com/955-0192_v7.3/RANGER_GEMINI_HTML_v7.3/Content/5_Advanced_Menus/1_Settings/Recording/Avid_Info.htm

Another place I looked is in the AAFSDK (CAAFDNxHDCodec.cpp):

```cpp
    switch(_ComprID)
    {
    case 1235: FormatNumber=DNX_220X_1080p_COMPRESSION_ID;  break;
    case 1237: FormatNumber=DNX_145_1080p_COMPRESSION_ID;  break;
    case 1238: FormatNumber=DNX_220_1080p_COMPRESSION_ID;  break;
    case 1241: FormatNumber=DNX_220X_1080i_COMPRESSION_ID;  break;
    case 1242: FormatNumber=DNX_145_1080i_COMPRESSION_ID;  break;
    case 1243: FormatNumber=DNX_220_1080i_COMPRESSION_ID;  break;
    case 1244: FormatNumber=DNX_145_1440_1080i_COMPRESSION_ID;  break;
    case 1250: FormatNumber=DNX_220X_720p_COMPRESSION_ID;  break;
    case 1251: FormatNumber=DNX_220_720p_COMPRESSION_ID; break;
    case 1252: FormatNumber=DNX_145_720p_COMPRESSION_ID; break;
    case 1253: FormatNumber=DNX_36_1080p_COMPRESSION_ID;  break;
    //case 1254: FormatNumber=DNX_50_1080i_COMPRESSION_ID;  break;
    default:
        FormatNumber=DNX_36_1080p_COMPRESSION_ID;  //make any guess
        break;
    }
```

Please also take a look at an earlier commit of the dnxhddec.c:

```c
static int dnxhd_decode_macroblock(const DNXHDContext *ctx, RowContext *row,
                                   AVFrame *frame, int x, int y)
{
    ...
    act = get_bits1(&row->gb);
    if (act) {
        static int warned = 0;
        if (!warned) {
            warned = 1;
            av_log(ctx->avctx, AV_LOG_ERROR,
                   "Unsupported adaptive color transform, patch welcome.\n");
        }
    }
    ...
```

And its commit message:

> Christophe Gisquet  Christophe Gisquet, 5 years ago   (September 25th,
> 2015 11:07pm)
>
> dnxhddec: parse and print adaptive color transform
>
> Indicates a YCbCr->RGB transform at the block level. Although nothing
> explicitly states it, this would assume the actual content is planar
> RGB.
>
> Currently unsupported, but the one sequence I found using it flagged
> every mb that way, actually meaning the content was YCbCr, and thus
> best left to the output format to decide what to do of it.

---

Edit:

I'm still in the search of the DNxHD codec specifications.

I have yet to fully understand the code. But if the author had said that it's currently unsupported (5 years ago), and that some sequence had shown conflicting meanings, shouldn't this be ignored instead of generating an error?

In our case, not every mb was flagged. It could be flagged in a particular shot of the video, and hence the error would only pop up at the very first frame of the shot. This also means that our pipeline can somehow create both flagged and unflagged outputs with seemingly all YCbCr footages. And the mixdown version of the sequence preserves all flagged and unflagged macroblocks.

---

Thanks for reading this far.

### Questions:

1. What is the meaning of setting the ACT flag to true in a YCbCr 4:2:2 video?
2. Does it mean the opposite if set to true in a RGB 4:4:4 video?
3. Could this error be safely ignored? Why?
4. Should ffmpeg be modified to ignore the flag?

Thank you very much!

### P.S.:

Although not exactly the same error, I came across this never answered question:
https://www.mail-archive.com/ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org/msg23397.html

Like the OP, I'm also unable to provide a sample at this stage. I'm trying to reproduce such video with some public domain materials so that I may share later. Although, by then, I might have the answer to my questions already.

---

Edit2:

Still struggling from creating a sample video from scratch. But I've rewrapped a portion of a video, [10 frames of black](https://www.dropbox.com/s/enebtvm85kqtnii/pure_black_10f.mxf?dl=0), which we found with the ACT flag set.

I suspect that this is related to some Color Grading plugins, but I'm unable to verify, since often when we detects the error, only the mixdown version remains and with all footages already deleted.

---

Edit3:

I was looking at a macroblock of the first frame. I believe this is the start of it.

> file offset 0x4094: **00 3F** 87 FA 28 A2 8A 28 A2 80 18 A2 8A 28 A2 8A

And I believe this bolded 1 bit is the ACT flag?

> 0000 0000 001**1** 1111

I tried to change every macroblock (1080i video, 34 macroblocks per field) in the first frame to this:

> **00 2F** or 0000 0000 001**0** 1111

But ffmpeg still considered the macroblocks "ACT flagged", although it did not complain about my changes.

Am I missing something?

Much appreciated!

Comment: I wonder what 's the original value of `row->format` in the problematic case. Try printing it in the log when `!ctx->act`.

Comment: Also print `act` (the local one), although it's probably always `1`.

Comment: @Tom Thank you for your comment. I have yet to setup my machine to compile ffmpeg, so I might not be able to print those log. `row-format` gets initialized to `-1` before coming into this function. So this probably translate into two cases when `act && ctx->act`: A) `row->format = act` if it is still `-1`, B) `row->format = 2` if it is no longer `-1` and `act` is changed among macroblocks. Since `act` is always `1` in my sample, printing `row->format` inside `!ctx->act` block could yield `-1` or `1`. But since `ctx->act` is also constant, it will only print `-1` or it will not print at all.

Comment: Hence I wonder whether the code should instead either set `row->format` to `act` (i.e. `1`?) or warn about `! ctx->act` when and only when `raw->format == - 1 && act`, except I don't know if `raw->format` would always be `-1` upon the check then, and if it needs to be change to `2` when it is ever `0`.

Comment: @Tom If both the frame header `ctx->act` and the first macroblock `act` are `1` (for 4:4:4 videos), `row->format` will be set to `act`. The next mb `act` might have a `0`, then `row->format` will be set to `2`. Since this should not happen, a `2` will get you the "Unsupported: variable ACT flag" error later on, but only when `ctx->act` is `1`.

Comment: The code doesn't look like it cares about the `act` flag too much for a 4:2:2 video, but it generates an error anyways when `act && !ctx->act`. In violation, indeed, but I don't see any code handling the frame decode differently according to the `act` being set. I'd think that the code should decide whether to error out or not by also checking `ctx->is_444` in this case.